# Symfony - What is required to create a plugin?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I've been going through the Symfony documentation in order to find out how to create a plugin. However, the two tutorials seem to give a lot of extra information (for example models etc).

What I'd like to know is, what is the absolute minimum requirement in order to get a controller and template working from a plugin directory?

For example, just an index action and a corresponding 'Hello World' template.

Also, is the routing for this automatic or do I have to manually change something?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do what youre askign you would need the following:

```
MyPlugin/
  modules/
    my_module/
      actions/
        actions.class.php
      templates/
        indexSuccess.php
```

You would then need to enable the plugin in you ProjectConfiguration and also enable the module in your settings.yml for any apps you want to use it.

Routing is not automatic. You need to add routes manually to routing.yml or you can create a listener and appends/prepends the routes when `routing.load_configuration` is fired. USing the second option would also imply creating a `PluginConfiguration` class where you listeners connect to the event via the event dispatcher.

Basically a Plugin follows the same basic structure as an application - except pretty much everything is optional. Whether or not you need to do somethign really depends on what your plugin does. Also you might want to take a look at using `sfTaskExtraPlugin` it has a task for generating a basic plugin skeleton and a plugin module skeleton.

Answer (score 0):

some examples

enable the plugin in you ProjectConfiguration
go to 'core\config\ProjectConfiguration.class.php' and add next code in setup()

```
$this->enablePlugins('MyPlugin');
```

enable the module in your settings.yml

```
all:
  .settings:
    enabled_modules:  [my_module]
```